# deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found

Tags: android, flutter, adb, avd-manager

I installed Android Studio 4.0. Added Flutter plugin. Installed Flutter already. Flutter doctor also showed everything is running well.

```
> C:\Users\Alvin>flutter doctor 
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): 
> [√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale en-US)
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0) 
> [√] Android Studio (version 4.0) [√] VS Code (version 1.45.1) 
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
> 
> • No issues found!
```

But when I open AVD Manager and launch the AVD in the emulator. I also got a pop-up [image]

But actually the adb is installed already in C:\Users\Alvin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools.
So I add the path into the environment variable PATH to include this directory.
And I can call the adb from anywhere in the command prompt.

But the same "Unable to locate adb still pop up every time I launch AVD.
Actually, if I generate a simple Flutter program and run it in a mobile connected to the USB, it work in the mobile device.

Based on curiosity, I try to figure out what is actually happening. I opened the log file idea.log (open using Help -> Show log in explorer). I found out that the system actually trying to find ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT. After I set them up, the Android Studio seems to be running well but there is a message that is still annoying. .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found
Even though it is INFO only, I suspect this is the same problem when launching AVD Manager.
the list of the log is as follows

```
2020-06-19 22:50:39,009 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2020-06-19 22:50:39,213 [    204]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 154 ms 
2020-06-19 22:50:39,610 [    601]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, 20 May 2020 22:07) 
2020-06-19 22:50:39,610 [    601]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2020-06-19 22:50:39,610 [    601]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2020-06-19 22:50:39,610 [    601]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.242-b01 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2020-06-19 22:50:39,614 [    605]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: exit -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\server -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio4.0 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\Alvin\java_error_in_studio_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\Alvin\java_error_in_studio.hprof 
2020-06-19 22:50:39,618 [    609]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext: [access-bridge-64.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2020-06-19 22:50:39,618 [    609]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - charsets: JNU=Cp1252 file=Cp1252 
2020-06-19 22:50:39,635 [    626]   INFO - ntellij.idea.ApplicationLoader - CPU cores: 4; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@c001ec7[Running, parallelism = 3, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@d88ff34 
2020-06-19 22:50:39,985 [    976]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2020-06-19 22:50:40,976 [   1967]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin "Groovy" misses optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2020-06-19 22:50:40,978 [   1969]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin "Groovy" misses optional descriptor duplicates-detection-groovy.xml 
2020-06-19 22:50:41,360 [   2351]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin "Java" misses optional descriptor profiler-java.xml 
2020-06-19 22:50:41,532 [   2523]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android APK Support (1.0), Android Games (1.0), Android NDK Support (1.0), Android Support (10.4.0), App Links Assistant (0.1), ChangeReminder (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Compose (0.1.0-dev03), Configuration Script (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Copyright (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Coverage (193.6911.18.40.6514223), EditorConfig (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Firebase App Indexing (0.1), Firebase Services (0.1), Firebase Testing (1.0), Git (193.6911.18.40.6514223), GitHub (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Google Cloud Tools Core (0.2.8), Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Developers Samples (0.3.1), Google Login (1.0), Google Services (0.1), Gradle (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Gradle-Java (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Groovy (193.6911.18.40.6514223), IDEA CORE (193.6911.18.40.6514223), IntelliLang (193.6911.18.40.6514223), JUnit (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Java (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Java Bytecode Decompiler (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Java IDE Customization (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Java Internationalization (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Java Stream Debugger (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Kotlin (1.3.72-release-Studio4.0-1), Layoutlib Native (1.0), Layoutlib Standard (1.0), Mercurial (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Properties (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Settings Repository (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Shell Script (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Smali Support (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Subversion (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Task Management (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Terminal (193.6911.18.40.6514223), Test Recorder (1.0), TestNG (193.6911.18.40.6514223), TextMate bundles (193.6911.18.40.6514223), YAML (193.6911.18.40.6514223) 
2020-06-19 22:50:41,532 [   2523]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: Dart (193.7361), Flutter (46.0.2) 
2020-06-19 22:50:43,023 [   4014]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=1226 
2020-06-19 22:50:43,053 [   4044]   INFO - tellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil - interruptible FileChannel-s will be used for indexes 
2020-06-19 22:50:43,295 [   4286]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2020-06-19 22:50:43,425 [   4416]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2020-06-19 22:50:43,444 [   4435]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2020-06-19 22:50:43,529 [   4520]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2020-06-19 22:50:43,558 [   4549]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0 
2020-06-19 22:50:43,597 [   4588]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2020-06-19 22:50:44,105 [   5096]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "ReSharper" not found [Plugin: com.android.tools.ndk] 
2020-06-19 22:50:45,429 [   6420]   WARN - ins.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData - Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Alvin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools.old' (Expected 'C:\Users\Alvin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools') 
2020-06-19 22:50:45,429 [   6420]   WARN - ins.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData - Already observed package id 'platform-tools' in 'C:\Users\Alvin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\Alvin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools.old' 
2020-06-19 22:50:45,650 [   6641]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done: 1992 
2020-06-19 22:50:46,465 [   7456]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done: 799 
2020-06-19 22:50:50,013 [  11004]   INFO - artup.AndroidStudioInitializer - Failed to disable 'org.intellij.plugins.intelliLang.inject.groovy.GrConcatenationInjector' 
2020-06-19 22:50:50,175 [  11166]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2020-06-19 22:50:51,671 [  12662]   WARN - ugins.textmate.TextMateService - Missing builtin bundles, checked: 
C:/Users/Alvin/.AndroidStudio4.0/config/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles
C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles 
2020-06-19 22:50:51,712 [  12703]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:50:52,412 [  13403]   INFO - lutter.run.daemon.DeviceDaemon - starting Flutter device daemon #1: C:/flutterSDK/flutter/bin/flutter.bat daemon 
2020-06-19 22:50:52,420 [  13411]   INFO - #io.flutter.sdk.FlutterCommand - C:\flutterSDK\flutter\bin\flutter.bat [--no-color, config, --machine] 
2020-06-19 22:50:52,441 [  13432]   INFO -     #io.flutter.sdk.FlutterSdk - Calling config --machine 
2020-06-19 22:50:53,707 [  14698]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 493ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-06-19 22:50:53,804 [  14795]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider 
2020-06-19 22:50:54,741 [  15732]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 1032ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-06-19 22:50:55,874 [  16865]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 588 ms 
2020-06-19 22:50:56,113 [  17104]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
2020-06-19 22:50:56,597 [  17588]   INFO - ngd.lsp.ClangDaemonContextImpl - Using clangd from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\clang\win\clangd.exe 
2020-06-19 22:50:56,651 [  17642]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 647 ms 
2020-06-19 22:50:56,678 [  17669]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Header Maps finished in 27 ms 
2020-06-19 22:50:56,730 [  17721]   INFO - #io.flutter.sdk.FlutterCommand - C:\flutterSDK\flutter\bin\flutter.bat [--no-color, config, --machine] 
2020-06-19 22:50:56,733 [  17724]   INFO -     #io.flutter.sdk.FlutterSdk - Calling config --machine 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,254 [  18245]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 543 ms 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,279 [  18270]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 5678ms; general responsiveness: 1/6 sluggish; EDT responsiveness: 3/5 sluggish 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,282 [  18273]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 module maps in 0 packs for 0 search roots 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,304 [  18295]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saved 0 module maps in 0 packs 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,326 [  18317]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 23 ms 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,326 [  18317]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,327 [  18318]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,360 [  18351]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Updating Symbols finished in 24 ms 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,363 [  18354]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,368 [  18359]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Updating Symbols finished in 5 ms 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,368 [  18359]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Updating Symbols finished in 5 ms 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,402 [  18393]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,414 [  18405]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 12 ms 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,446 [  18437]   INFO -     #io.flutter.sdk.FlutterSdk - Timeout when calling flutter config --machine 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,481 [  18472]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - C:/Projects/android/Flutter/first_flutter_app/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,694 [  18685]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Load external projects data in 8 millis (read time: 1) 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,827 [  18818]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 11239 ms 
2020-06-19 22:50:57,872 [  18863]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:50:58,214 [  19205]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:50:58,909 [  19900]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 4 
2020-06-19 22:50:58,946 [  19937]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:50:59,228 [  20219]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:50:59,730 [  20721]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:51:00,306 [  21297]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:51:00,759 [  21750]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:51:01,274 [  22265]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:51:01,783 [  22774]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:51:02,222 [  23213]   INFO -     #io.flutter.sdk.FlutterSdk - Timeout when calling flutter config --machine 
2020-06-19 22:51:02,288 [  23279]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:51:02,789 [  23780]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:51:03,640 [  24631]   INFO - j.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper - using cached plugin list (updated at 6/19/2020 8:30 PM) 
2020-06-19 22:51:06,694 [  27685]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:51:07,458 [  28449]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - 
Exit code 1 
2020-06-19 22:51:09,822 [  30813]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:51:15,262 [  36253]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:51:15,362 [  36353]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 1126 ms 
2020-06-19 22:51:19,857 [  40848]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:51:59,968 [  80959]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:52:04,295 [  85286]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appHttpConfigurable took 16 ms 
2020-06-19 22:52:04,326 [  85317]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:52:04,342 [  85333]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=first_flutter_app, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Projects\android\Flutter\first_flutter_app) ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration took 16 ms 
2020-06-19 22:56:13,286 [ 334277]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:56:13,786 [ 334777]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:56:14,301 [ 335292]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:56:14,817 [ 335808]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:56:15,332 [ 336323]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:56:17,379 [ 338370]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:56:19,925 [ 340916]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:56:20,956 [ 341947]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:56:21,472 [ 342463]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-06-19 22:56:23,504 [ 344495]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found
```

Are there any information that can be shared about what I am facing and how to fix it?
Additional information:
adb version : 30.0.3-6597393
java version:  1.8.0_121

Answer (score 1):

After spending days on this issue and didn't get any responses from Stackoverflow. I try a different approach. I uninstalled the Android Studio 4.0 completely including the Android SDK.
Then I installed Android Studio 3.4. Setup Android SDK not in C:\Users{name}\android...
But create my own folder for the Android SDK. Installed it. Then setup ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_SDK_HOME in environment variables. Put the ANDROID_HOME in the path list. Then start the Android Studio. ADB work, everything works properly.
After a while, I click the upgrade prompt to upgrade to Android Studio 4.0. Everything works properly. Then I installed the flutter plugin.
Now everything works perfectly.
But I still don't know why I got the problem in the first place.
I just know by reinstalling, everything works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem. A reinstallation did not solve the problem. I found the faulty ZIP file in the log file. It was gradle-6.1.1-all.zip, the download is from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/. It had to be replaced in C: \ Users \ xxxYourNamexxx \ .gradle \ wrapper \ dists \ gradle-6.1.1-all \ cfmwm155h49vnt3hynmlrsdst
I replaced it and then it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I didn't realize it. I will check it out. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add adb to your PATH.

Check if ADB is installed:
`~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb`

If that doesn't print, you have to install adb:

1. Launch Android Studio
2. Launch SDK Manager via Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager
3. Check Android SDK Platform-Tools

If it prints, run `echo export "PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile`

Restart your terminal and you should be good! Verify adb works by running `adb`

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Turns out to be Android SDK issue.

1. Navigate to SDK folder
2. Delete the folder
3. Re-Downlaod the SDK using Android Studio